# Illustrator issue on top bar : font style panel and opacity's one overlapping

Tags: adobe-illustrator

In Illustrator I have this strange problem on the top bar: the font style panel and the opacity's one are overlapping so that I have to make impressive mouse moves to have one of them selected.

Why this problem??

[image]

Comment: First thought of mine was that maybe your window width is not enough to fit them all in there properly, even if that would be the case, this should not happen. Have you tried to restart illustrator?

Comment: yes it alway happens!

Comment: Is there still room left in that toolbar or is the window width restricting it? Cause, either way that seems like a bug to me, but it could be that if currently the width is not enough to hold them all properly, making it wider might work for a while. I do have a feeling that resetting the settings wouldn't help. I would probably just reinstall or repair.

Comment: What's your monitor resolution?

Comment: @Scott 1280x800

Comment: Reset all your windows and palettes to default. Toss your preferences. Reboot the machine.

Comment: Well that is a new one one me. I'd have to agree with Farray that it may just be a bug. Or there are issues with your system.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it looks like just a plain ol'-fashioned *bug* in the menus/toolbars system that Illustrator uses.  You can report it at http://www.adobe.com/misc/bugreport.html

The typical things to try are trashing your preferences, resetting your workspace, and updating your graphics drivers.  Also make sure that Adobe Update Agent is running and Illustrator is up to date.  If none of that works, try uninstalling/reinstalling.

Comment: Resetting the workspace and trashing preferences would definitely be the starting points. I've never seen this on any version of AI, so that makes preferences corruption a strong suspect.

Answer (score 0):

If your screen Resolution is to low, the panels will be hidden when everything is ok with illustrator ...

You could try to switch the Workspace (Window -> Workspace) or make a complete new one.